# Justification for $\varepsilon$-ball around limit point not in set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $S$ is a subset of a normed vector space, and $S$ has certain characteristics which can lead us to conclude that it contains all its limit points, and is thus closed. As far as I know, one of the techniques for proving that $S$ contains all its limit points is by assuming that if some limit point $x$ of $S$ is not in $S$, then there exists an open $\varepsilon$-ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \cap S=\emptyset$. But is this actually possible? If $\{x_n\}\in S$, a sequence converging to the limit point $x$, must be entirely contained in $S$, then it must contain points arbitrarily close to $x$, which means that there cannot exist an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap S=\emptyset$.

I would appreciate some input in this respect.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the method being used is proof by contradiction is confusing you? For if you do have a sequence in S converging towards x then it is indeed a limit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused in your description of "one of the techniques for proving that $S$ contains all its limit points". What you probably mean is the following: $S$ contains all its limit points iff $S$ is closed iff the complement of $S$ is open. And in order to prove that the complement $V\setminus S$ is open (where $V$ is the space), we pick an arbitrary point $x\in V\setminus S$, i.e. $x\notin S$, and demonstrate that there exists an open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq V\setminus S$, which is the same as saying $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap S=\emptyset$. Note that we pick **any $x$ not in $S$**, not "a limit point $x$ of $S$ not in $S$".

And as you pointed out yourself, for $x$ a limit point of $S$ it is impossible to have $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap S=\emptyset$. So your reasoning in the end of your post is correct.

Comment: But, on the other hand, if $x$ is a limit point of $S$ with $x\not\in S$, then, by what you wrote above, it should be true that $x\in V\backslash S$, which implies that there exists an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap S=\emptyset$. So how do we reconcile this?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply that. If $x$ is a limit point of $S$ not in $S$, then in fact $x$ is a limit point of $V\setminus S$ as well, by definition of limit points. $x\in V\setminus S$ only means that $x$ is a point in $x\in V\setminus S$, **not** that $x$ is an *interior* point of $x\in V\setminus S$.